# Configuring Allied Telesis AT-9000/28

Tags: switch

I am trying to configure an Allied Telesis AT-9000/28.  It comes with an RJ-45 to DB-9 connector but my computers lack a serial port.

What are my options? I'm on the LAN/same subnet, can I network in (ie "telnet"?).  If I got an RJ-45 to USB connector, would it seamlessly connect to the switch?  Or would I need a serial to USB software/adapter driver?

Second question in case someone here is familiar, I would like to set a static ARP table because my router doesn't seem to keep it set.  I assume if this switch allows me to configure the ARP table manually, I'll be able to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can purchase a USB to Serial converter. They all should come with their own driver software. You should be able to connect to the console port with that. Something like this should work - http://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-RS-232-Serial-Converter-TU-S9/dp/B0007T27H8

Comment: The reason for the ARP table part is likely this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/646420/wake-on-lan-works-w-magic-packet-but-not-w-net-activity

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to a local session (with the serial cable and a serial/usb converter if necessary) to create an initial IP configuration. After that, you can use a web interface for further config. All this is outlined in the docs which are [easy to find](http://www.alliedtelesis.de/switches/9000-28). Why didn't you try this first?

Comment: Thanks Sven. I was at their site but was directed to register to access their software (my CD is outdated). Didn't realize their docs were open.

Answer (score 0):

If the switch has correct IP configuration, you can use telnet / web management. http://www.alliedtelesis.com/switches/9000-28 has the documentation for the switch, you can see the details there.

Switches don't manage ARP tables, as they are only forwarding Ethernet frames based on MAC addresses. They don't care about the L3 addresses.

Serial-to-USB connector is useful to have for managing network devices.

Comment: Thanks so much. If my router can't manage an ARP table (Apple Airport Extreme - latest model), then my only option is to buy another router?  Was hoping this switch would do it for me.

Comment: @DanielForward: Please edit your question to elaborate on what problem you want to solve with your static ARP table approach.